# How do I iterate through this Firebase JSON?

Tags: json, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the JSON content I have uploaded in Firebase database.
Now I need to access this in my Angular 2 app.
I am getting undefined and NaN while trying to access the objects.

```
{
      "clients" : {
        "clients" : {
          "-Kdl_wRRkn7nJxgz4B54" : {
            "balance" : "100.00",
            "email" : "jdoe@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "John",
            "lastName" : "Doe",
            "phone" : "555-555-5555"
          },
          "-KdleehAQm0HgVFYdkUo" : {
            "balance" : "350.00",
            "email" : "stevesmith@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "Steve",
            "lastName" : "Smith",
            "phone" : "444-444-4444"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am trying to access this here

```
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {
  clients:any[];
  totalOwed:number;

  constructor(
    public clientService:ClientService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => {
      this.clients = clients;
      console.log(this.clients);
      this.getTotalOwed();
    });
  }

  getTotalOwed(){
    let total = 0;
    for(let i = 0;i < this.clients.length;i++){
      console.log(this.clients[i]);
      total += parseFloat(this.clients[i].balance);
    }
    this.totalOwed = total;
    console.log(this.totalOwed);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should re-structure your JSON, the structure below will be better for looping through, and a better practice. second, the reason you are getting not a number is because you are not accessing the balance key's value.

your code to loop through the data structure below would look something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.clients.length(); i++) {
    console.log(this.clients[i].balance)
}
```

and the JSON:

```
{
  "clients" : [
    {
      "id" : "-Kdl_wRRkn7nJxgz4B54",
      "balance" : "100.00",
      "email" : "jdoe@gmail.com",
      "firstName" : "John",
      "lastName" : "Doe",
      "phone" : "555-555-5555"
     },
     {
       "id" : "-KdleehAQm0HgVFYdkUo",
       "balance" : "350.00",
       "email" : "stevesmith@gmail.com",
       "firstName" : "Steve",
       "lastName" : "Smith",
       "phone" : "444-444-4444"
     }
   ]
}
```